# Adding text from property after each row in table gsp

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I want to add some text from an object property after each row of a table that contains a list of objects!

each row presents some properties and i need to add text that is passed from a property as well ( in div or some other container) under each row .

is there anyway to do this ?! 
all tips appreciated !

Here is sample of my code !

```
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <g:sortableColumn />
        <g:sortableColumn />
        <g:sortableColumn />
        <g:sortableColumn />
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <g:each in="${fpsList}" var="ft">
            <tr>
                <td> ${ft.sth}</td>
                <td> ${ft.sth1}</td>
                <td> ${ft.sth2}</td>

           /*i need to do some thing like this
 <div> Note:${ft.information </div> */

        </tr>

        </g:each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you using scaffolding for the views as well? You will not be able to do so unless you use your own views, or you modify the model.

Comment: No am using my own views actually!

Comment: is this about how to do it regarding to HTML or to GSP/Grails? it would help, if you could add some code/example what you are after or have already tried.

Comment: i've added sample of my code ! hope it helps

Comment: after the closing `</tr>` add `<tr><td colspan="3"><div>${ft.information}</div></td></tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add another row below the existing row for each domain class in your list you simply need to add another `<tr>` after the existing one.

For example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <g:sortableColumn />
    <g:sortableColumn />
    <g:sortableColumn />
    <g:sortableColumn />
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${fpsList}" var="ft">
        <tr>
            <td>${ft.sth}</td>
            <td>${ft.sth1}</td>
            <td>${ft.sth2}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div>Note:${ft.information}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What the above does is add another row, with a single column that spans the width of the three columns in the table. Placing the data `div` and domain property within it.

There are plenty of good HTML guides out there. W3Schools is a nice place to start [learning](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: thank you ! trying to remove the border of the first row so it looks good ! what is the best css property to do this ? tried a bunch none worked